# When to properly use colon?

Tags: colons

Which of the following instructions is correct?

Solve the following equations:

1-5 equations

or

Solve the following equations.

1-5 equations

I'm not sure if I need to use a colon or just a period.

Comment: You may want to read through a similar question asked over on English Language & Usage: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/394859/what-is-the-correct-punctuation-after-as-follows